# how to create the product sales report in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, reports

I want to create product sales report like below

[image]

When admin enter sku name he will get result of all the product list with status completed and according to applied filter. Please suggest me right way to do this.

Comment: You need to check Admin->Reports->Products->Products Ordered.
You need to customized this according to your requirement.

Comment: actually i created this kind of layout but i need all the order which have  input sku and status complete according to this form. how can i do this @Dhiren

Comment: For that you need to customized some code.